# Type 'BusinessParameter[]' has no properties in common with type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql, pinia

I have an API function with the return type of `Promise<BusinessParameter[]>` because what it resolves to is an array of BusinessParameters. Then I have set the same type for the variable where I assign it (`returnOrderItemBusinessParameters: [] as BusinessParameter`) but for some reason TypeScript is complaining and I am not sure why. *This is a Vue 3 project with Pinia and Vue Apollo.*

**Here is the error that I'm getting**:

```
[vue-tsc] Type 'BusinessParameter[]' has no properties in common with type '{ __typename?: "BusinessParameter"; id?: number; entity?: string; type?: string; isRequired?: boolean; nameTranslated?: string; descriptionTranslated?: string; technicalName?: string; value?: string; dataArray?: any; }'.
/var/www/app/src/services/businessParametersService.ts:10:5
  
     8 |     const result = await businessParametersApi.getBusinessParametersForEntity('ReturnOrderItem')
     9 |
  > 10 |     returnOrderStore.returnOrderItemBusinessParameters = result
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    11 | }
    12 |
    13 | export { loadBusinessParameters }
```

This is the type definition for `BusinessParameter`:

```
export interface BusinessParameter {
    __typename?: "BusinessParameter"
    id?: Maybe<Scalars["Int"]>
    entity?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>
    type?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>
    isRequired?: Maybe<Scalars["Boolean"]>
    nameTranslated?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>
    descriptionTranslated?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>
    technicalName?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>
    value?: Maybe<Scalars["String"]>
    dataArray?: Maybe<Scalars["JsonObject"]>
}
```

This is what my store looks like where `returnOrderItemBusinessParameters` is an array of BusinessParameters:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { BusinessParameter } from '@/types/graphql/graphql'

export const useReturnOrderStore = defineStore('returnOrder', {
    state: () => ({
        returnOrderItemBusinessParameters: [] as BusinessParameter,
    }),
})
```

Then I have my api function like this (`result.data.getBusinessParameterClassifier` is the array of BusinessParameters):

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { useLazyQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { BusinessParameter } from '@/types/graphql/graphql'
import { OptionsParameter } from '@vue/apollo-composable/dist/useQuery'
import { defaultQueryOptions, getGraphQLEndpoint } from '@/services/graphQLService'

export default {
    getBusinessParametersForEntity(entity: string): Promise<BusinessParameter[]> {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const { load: loadBusinessParameters, onResult, onError } = useLazyQuery(gql`
                query getBusinessParameterClassifier($entity: String!) {
                    getBusinessParameterClassifier(entity: $entity) {
                        id
                        technicalName
                        nameTranslated
                        descriptionTranslated
                        type    
                        isRequired
                        dataArray
                    }
                }
            `)

            loadBusinessParameters()

            onResult(result => resolve(result.data.getBusinessParameterClassifier))
            onError(error => reject(error))
        })
    }
}
```

The response of the api call from the server looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getBusinessParameterClassifier": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "technicalName": "amount",
        "nameTranslated": "Amount",
        "descriptionTranslated": "amount",
        "type": "decimal",
        "isRequired": false,
        "dataArray": "[]",
        "__typename": "BusinessParameter"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is the code that calls the api and assigns it to `returnOrderItemBusinessParameters` but it fails with the error message I mentioned above:

```
const loadBusinessParameters = async () => {
    const result = await businessParametersApi.getBusinessParametersForEntity('ReturnOrderItem')

    // Error: Type 'BusinessParameter[]' has no properties in common with type '{ __typename?: "BusinessParameter"; id?: number; entity?: string; type?: string; isRequired?: boolean; nameTranslated?: string; descriptionTranslated?: string; technicalName?: string; value?: string; dataArray?: any; }'
    returnOrderStore.returnOrderItemBusinessParameters = result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the problem was with the type in my store.

```
-returnOrderItemBusinessParameters: [] as BusinessParameter,
+returnOrderItemBusinessParameters: [] as BusinessParameter[],
```